# Is it possible to calibrate camera from single image with known 9 points?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have only one image with at least 12 points : I can have at least 8 points at one plane(Football pitch coordinates at football pitch plane) and at least 4 on another plane like Football goal) .

a) Is it possible to get camera intrinsic,extrinsic and distortion parameters ?
b) What is minimal amount of pictures required to perform calibration

I was able to use opencv calibrateCamera and then use it with undistort function, but undistort works on some images and doesn't work on others .